# vscode shows errors all over the project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I have cloned a repo and it contains a dockerfile and a docker-compose when I run this command
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build

the react project is started fine but vscode keeps showing errors related to node modules such as
Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime' or its corresponding type declarations.ts

this is my docker compose

```
services:
  celus_travel_blog_server:
  container_name: celus_travel_blog_server
  build:
    context: ./api
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment:
    - HOST=0.0.0.0
    - PORT=8080
  volumes:
    - ./api/db.json:/app/db.json
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"

celus_travel_blog_ui:
  container_name: celus_travel_blog_ui
  build:
    context: ./ui
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  depends_on:
    - celus_travel_blog_server
  environment:
    - API_HOST=celus_travel_blog_server:8080
  volumes:
    - ./ui/src:/app/src
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

and this is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:18.6-bullseye

ARG APP_ROOT=/app
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}

ENV PATH ${APP_ROOT}/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json yarn.lock tsconfig.json .eslintrc.json ./

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY public/ ./public
COPY src/ ./src

EXPOSE 3000

CMD yarn start
```

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install` in your root directory? Usually you will get such errors when you don't have `node_modules` folder available locally. These are usually not carried over when cloning a repo as `node_modules` is present in the `.gitignore` file.